# Word Order in Search Bars Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Explanation.** I am new to VueJS and JavaScript and I am trying to setup a search bar. So far, it works well, but I have one issue with it. I would like to be able to search through a description of an object even if the words I typed in the search bar are not in the correct order.

**Example.**
The string in the description would be "Gucci blue belt". If I type "Gucci blue", the result shows up since the description contains those words in this exact order. Therefore, I would like to add the functionality for which I can type "Gucci belt" and the item with the description "Gucci blue belt" would show up.

**My current code in the computed section in VueJS**

```
   filteredsortedobjects (){
    return this.sortedobjects.filter(object => {
      var Objectslist_n = object.name;
      var Objectslist_q = object.quantity;
      var Objectslist_c = object.category;
      var Objectslist_s = object.section;
      var Objectslist_d = object.description;
      var Objectslist_date = object.reception_date;
      var Input = this.searchQuery;

      /* Form arrays with all the information in the table */

      var Objectslist_nq = Objectslist_n.concat(Objectslist_q);
      var Objectslist_nqc = Objectslist_nq.concat(Objectslist_c);
      var Objectslist_nqcs = Objectslist_nqc.concat(Objectslist_s);
      var Objectslist_nqcsd = Objectslist_nqcs.concat(Objectslist_d);
      var Objectslist_nqcsddate = Objectslist_nqcsd.concat(Objectslist_date);

      /* Filtered variables */

      var F_Objectslist = RemoveAccents(Objectslist_nqcsddate.toLowerCase());
      var F_Input = RemoveAccents(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase());

      /* Function to remove accents */

      function RemoveAccents(str) {
        var accents    = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž';
        var accentsOut = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz";
        str = str.split('');
        var strLen = str.length;
        var i, x;
        for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
          if ((x = accents.indexOf(str[i])) != -1) {
            str[i] = accentsOut[x];
          }
        }
        return str.join('');
      };
      console.log(F_Objectslist);
      console.log(F_Input);
      return F_Objectslist.includes(F_Input)
    })
  }
```

I am aware that the function to remove accents is not yet used since I have been testing things.

**What I have tried doing.** I have tried setting the variable F_Input *(what is being written in the search bar)* and F_Objectslist *(a variable containing an array with all the words for the items, for instance, the names, the category, the section, the quantity, a description and a date)* as strings by array.split(" "). That way, I was able to have an array of strings in this format in the console ["word", "word2", ...] for both my variables.

From this point, I am unsure on how to check if the strings in my F_Input array are all present in the array for F_Objectslist even if they are in a different order.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Hi, if you have found the answer to your question by yourself post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. Please don't add solutions inside questions.

Comment: Hi, will do, thank you! I will be able to mark my answer as accepted in roughly 22 hours. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer.

I managed to make a quite responsive search bar that seeks information in the array! Here is the code if anyone is curious about it!

**page.vue inside computed**

```
   filteredsortedobjects (){
    return this.sortedobjects.filter(object => {
      var Objectslist_n = "a" + object.name;
      var Objectslist_c = object.category;
      var Objectslist_s = object.section;
      var Objectslist_q = object.quantity;
      var Objectslist_d = object.description;
      var Objectslist_date = object.reception_date;
      var Input = this.searchQuery;

      /* Form arrays with all the information in the table */

      var Objectslist_nc = Objectslist_n + " " + Objectslist_c;
      var Objectslist_ncs = Objectslist_nc + " " + Objectslist_s;
      var Objectslist_ncsq = Objectslist_ncs + " " + Objectslist_q;
      var Objectslist_ncsqd = Objectslist_ncsq + " " + Objectslist_d;
      var Objectslist_ncsqddate = Objectslist_ncsqd + " " + Objectslist_date;

      /* Filtered variables */

      var F_Objectslist = RemoveAccents(Objectslist_ncsqddate.toLowerCase()).split(" ") + " ";
      var F_Input = RemoveAccents(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()).split(" ");

      /* Function to remove accents */

      function RemoveAccents(str) {
        var accents    = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž';
        var accentsOut = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz";
        str = str.split('');
        var strLen = str.length;
        var i, x;
        for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
          if ((x = accents.indexOf(str[i])) != -1) {
            str[i] = accentsOut[x];
          }
        }
        return str.join('');
      };

      return F_Input.every(object => {
          if (F_Objectslist.indexOf(object) === -1) {
          }
          else {
            return F_Objectslist.indexOf(object)
          }
      })

    })
  }
```

I have an input with a v-model="searchQuery" attribute. Also, there is a table containing

```
   <tr id="tr" v-for="object in filteredsortedobjects" v-bind:key="object.name">
    <td>
      <p>{{ object.name }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>{{ object.category }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>{{ object.section }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>{{ object.quantity }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>{{ object.reception_date }}</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

The object.something are imported from a JSON file using

```
<script>
import objects from "./Database/Objects.json";
</script>
```

You would probably have to set some data information in the data() section

```
searchQuery: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Split `F_Input` on " ", then you can use 'Array.prototype.map()' to loop through the `F_Input` array of search terms using the same technique you have now.

Notice that I've chained all these together with a final call to the `.every()` method. That last one says that every `map` operation (search) must result in a true (or the result of the `map` operation must result in an array full of nothing but `true`);

```js
const F_Objectslist = "this is search term, and this is term search".split(' ');
const F_Input = "search term";

let result = search(F_Objectslist, F_Input);
console.log(result);

let notFoundResult = search(F_Objectslist, "search dog");
console.log(notFoundResult);

function search(text, terms) {
  return terms.split(' ').map(term =>text.includes(term)).every(found=>found===true);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help! I managed to do it and it's quite responsive too! Took me the whole afternoon, but it was worth the challenge. Thank you very much for taking the time to guide me through it! Next time... some backend so I can add information in my JSON file. I hope it won't take as long :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you were already pretty close, I would approach it like this

```
function searchString(input, match) {
  let is_a_match = true;

  const match_arr = match.split(' ');
  const input_arr = input.split(' ');

  input_arr.forEach(word => {
    if (match_arr.indexOf(word) === -1) {
        is_a_match = false;
    }
  });

  return is_a_match;
}
```

A working fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f02mydes/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code helped me figure it out. I changed it a little, but it works alright! I need to attempt adding more conditions and it should work fine. I'll keep you updated!